# assign and execute if/else conditions in single line

Tags: java, if-statement, ternary-operator

How can I do that for example, `if` block checks if the condition is `true` or `false` and then execute action depends on that condition?

like,

```
if (check true or false) 
         if false do action
         if true do action
```

Something like that do it all **in the same line without blocks**, it that possible ?

Sorry for my bad English

Thanks.

Comment: Why wihout blocks? It's mere syntax. Any reason?

Comment: People downvoting new users without even bothering to comment makes me sad.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [java ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java),

```
result = testCondition ? value1 : value2
```

this statement can be read as, If `testCondition` is true, assign the value of `value1` to `result`; otherwise, assign the value of `value2` to `result`.

simple example would be,

```
minVal = a < b ? a : b;
```

In above code, if the variable `a` is less than `b`, `minVal` is assigned the value of `a`; otherwise, `minVal` is assigned the value of `b`.

here is another example using `String`,

```
// result is assigned the value "it's false"
String result = false ? "that was true" : "it's false";
```

this examples would clear it more. It prints the salutation properly for a person's gender:

```
// if `person.isMale()` then its Mr. else its Ms. 
return = "Thank you " + (person.isMale() ? "Mr. " : "Ms. ") + person.getLastName() + ".";
```

**edit:**

> Question: you cannot call a method inside ternary operator.

No, this is incorrect.

You can call a method inside a ternary operator as long as it returns a value which is of the same type as the left-side of a ternary operator,

consider this example,

let's create a method that returns a `String` value,

```
String message(){
    return "This is returned value";
}
```

Now see this code,

```
String answer = false ? "true" : message();
```

this will execute just fine because `return` type of `message()` and variable type of `answer` are the same, i.e `String`.

**output:**

```
This is returned value
```

Comment: Thx, for the examples now i get it! So if(true) ? trueaction; : falseaction; would work no ?

Comment: `(true or false) ? (execute this if true) : (execute this if false) `

Comment: i mean if i can call a method there like for example (true)?System.out.println("true") : System.out.println("false") but i see that @neeraj-jain say that ternary operation cannot execute methods, but thx for all!

Comment: in your given condition, i.e `(true)?System.out.println("true") : System.out.println("false") ` what would be the left side of your statement ?, you can do this instead,  `System.out.print(false ? "true" : "false");`

Comment: Ok, thanks for all! the left side would be a check for ecample 'if(myNumber == 1) ? callTrueMethod; : callFalseMethod;' The method can be for example a void.

Comment: @peti446, neeraj answer is incorrect. You can call the method inside ternary operator. I have updated my answer please read it.

Comment: @SufiyanGhori Of course you can call a method in a ternary operator, but not a method with `void` return type. And given that OP used `do action` as placeholder for his methods, I think that those methods are _doing_ stuff rather than _returning_ stuff.

Comment: @tobias_k "Of course you can call a method in a ternary operator, but not a method with void return type." -- please read the edit part of my code, I made it clear to OP already.

Answer (score 2):

```
max = (a > b) ? a : b;
```

Is logically identical to

```
if (a > b) {
    max = a;
} else { max = b; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not use Ternary Operator as you can not invoke any **void method**     (i.e. the method which do not return anything ) from `Ternary Operator`

As it is not the intended use of the **ternary operator**.

If you really want it to be achieved in 1  line, you can write:

```
if (condition) doThisMethod(); else doThatMethod();
```

Answer (score 2):

For putting a conditional statement on one line, you *could* use the ternary operator. Note, however, that this can only be used in *assignments*, i.e. if the functions actually return something and you want to assign that value to a variable.

```
int abs = x > 0 ? x : -1;
```

If you want to execute methods, that do not return anything, but have some other side-effects, the ternary operator is not the right way to go. In fact, it does not even compile!

```
void doThis() {/* do this */}
void doThat() {/* do that */}

(condition) ? doThis() : doThat();  // does not work!
```

Instead, you should just use a plain-old `if-then-else`. It's also easier to read.

```
if (condition) {
    doThis();
} else {
    doThat();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [ternary operator](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018) does what you want:

```
checkIfTrue() ? actionIfTrue() : actionIfFalse();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really need a one-liner you could use this syntax (Known as ternary operator) :

> 1>0 ? "do action" : " Do other action";

An example would be this:

> String result = x>y ? "x>y" : "y>x";

But this is not recommended, most people hate this syntax because it can become very unreadable if you cascade several conditions inside it, or even worst cascade ternary operators.

But it has it's uses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a trenary operator:

```
if(condition) ? executeForTrue() : executeForFalse();
```

which I guess pretty much does what you want.